# PyPlot not showing on Windows

Tags: python-2.7

So I have my backend set to `atkgg` but `pyplot` still doesn't show the graph window. Code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def ex1():
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot([1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4], 'ro')
    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you actually calling your function?

Comment: Sorry I didn't call the function. That was dumb!